# Since some software is open source, can you add a feature you created and use it for your own personal use?

Tags: mit, derivative-works, private-changes

For example, if I want to add a bunch of lines in VS code using a single command and say I'm able to build this feature, can I use this on my version of VS code without the community acceptance?

Comment: A possible nuance to this question is, "can you modify the open source software underneath some proprietary software and thereby add new features or behaviors to the proprietary software?" For example, can I change something [here](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10156.html) and get new features in macOS?

Comment: Follow up question: What if the software I am modifying is not Open Source, but I legally own a copy of it? If I am only using the modified version myself, and not distributing it, would it still be legal? Could be as simple as changing the assets in a game to full blown decompile, change and compile.

Comment: @MAK That would be a question for the [law.se] site.

Comment: While the answers below answer the question about open-source, for this _specific_ case you may want to look into [writing a VS Code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), which would probably be a simpler way to achieve want you want, without having to maintain a modified copy of VS Code for your own use (pulling in updates as they come, etc...)

Comment: You might not even need a custom extension for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254732/can-vs-code-type-text-with-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Yes

### VSCode

Mureinik already pointed out that VSCode is [licensed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) under the [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) license, which is a permissive license. To quote from it (emphasis mine):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, **including
> without limitation the rights to** use, copy, **modify**, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software [...].

### More General

Since you are asking about open source software in general, I'll add a more general part to my answer.

#### Open Source

One of the elements of the [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd) is the right to modify software:

> #### 3. Derived Works
>
> The license must allow modifications and derived works, and must allow
> them to be distributed under the same terms as the license of the
> original software.

#### Free Software

The four essential freedoms required by the Free Software Definition also include the modification of software:

> 0. The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0).
> 1. The freedom to study how the program works, and change it so it does your computing as you wish (freedom 1). Access to the source code
>    is a precondition for this.
> 2. The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help others (freedom 2).
> 3. The freedom to distribute copies of your modified versions to others (freedom 3). By doing this you can give the whole community a
>    chance to benefit from your changes. Access to the source code is a
>    precondition for this.

## Conclusion

If the license of a software prohibits you from making any modifications to it, then it is neither [free nor open source](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html)!

Comment: Nicely researched, +1

Comment: Note that you might not be able to sell copies of the modified work, though, depending on the license involved.

Comment: @nick012000: Such a restriction would generally violate terms 1 and/or 3 of [The Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd), making the license not open source by, well, definition.

Comment: (That said, *some* restrictions on *how* you may sell the modified work may apply: most notably, the OSD only requires the license to permit sale and redistribution of modified works _under the same license terms_ as the original, and many [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) licenses do just that. With such a license, you may sell your modified version, but you must grant all your customers the right to resell and/or redistribute copies of it, too.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen “You can sell it but you have to give your customers the source code and the right to resell it” might as well be “you can’t sell it”, for all practical intents and purposes.

Comment: @nick012000 that is a misunderstanding, you can absolutely sell free software, in both theory and practice. see [here](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html) what the FSF has to say about it, or read one of the many questions on SE on that topic (e.g. the [first result](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278137/is-it-actually-possible-practically-to-sell-open-source-software) for "how to sell open source software")

Comment: @nonthevisor The answers to that Question just agree with me; you can't practically sell open source software; you have to make your money selling support for it, instead.

Comment: @nick012000 That's a _market reality_, though, more than a feature or characteristic of open source. In other words, there is **NOTHING** preventing you from selling your open-source software as a boxed, retail, pay-money-for-a-license-to-use-this-software product. The fact that you probably don't want to, because it's highly unlikely anyone could make money that way, has nothing to do with the open-source model and everything to do with the market. But it's certainly not impossible for a company to sell open-source software commercially. Just impractical.

Comment: @FeRD If something is impractical to do, you can't do it practically, by definition.

Comment: Come to think of it, one example of a company that's managed to do pretty much exactly that (sell open-source software) is [Qt](https://qt.io). They offer both open-source and commercial licenses for what is _largely_ the exact same software. Commercial licenses get sold to other companies that want to develop proprietary code free of open-source license terms, but in doing so Qt are effectively offering their open-source codebase as a retail software product.

Comment: @FeRD Which reinforced the claim by nick012000 that you can't sell it. The only reason Qt can sell their own software is because they sell the 'original' and they are able to sell the version without GPL.

Comment: @DavidMulder This is all completely off-topic to the question and I'm loathe to continue it, but: Not true. Qt (even commercial Qt) [incorporates a _large_ amount of open-source code](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/licenses-used-in-qt.html) that Qt **don't** own. The reason they can sell Qt commercially isn't that they wrote it all themselves, it's that they also make the full source code to those components freely available, fulfilling the terms of that code's open-source licenses.

Answer (score 19):

The freedom to modify a piece of software is an essential open-source freedom covered by any open-source license, specifically the MIT License which [VSCode is licensed under](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

In other words - you most certainly can do this.

Comment: Even notoriously "viral" licenses like the GPL allow this. You can modify GPL software for personal use all you like. The "share-alike" provisions only kick in when you *distribute* the modified copy. Not to mention, if you couldn't run a modified copy on your own machine, it would be nearly impossible to do development work on the software in the first place.

Comment: @bta I feel like there is some misunderstanding about the GPL here. you can modify software licensed under GPL all you want and distribute it any way you like. you just have to notice that you modified the work. the "viral" aspect only means that you can't take software licensed under GPL and re-license it under a less free license see [here](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility_analysis:_GPL) for comparison of "share alike" (which is part of CC) and GPLv3

Comment: @nonthevisor So in other words you can't distribute it any way you like - only in the ways the GPL allows.

Comment: @user253751 true, I see that my wording is unclear: I meant to say that you can distribute both the original and your modified version in the same way. of course you have to abide the license while doing it, which mostly means not making it proprietary and denying users your source code.

Comment: It is my understanding that if you do want to make GPL proprietary, you need to contact the original writer and get permission.

Comment: @user253751 In other words, you _can_ distribute it any way you like – where _it_ is the source code.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Still wrong. You can't distribute it under the MIT license.

Comment: @JohnGlen Yes, they can give you permission to ignore the GPL. (it's their work, they can give permission for whatever they want)

Answer (score 4):

You can do anything for your own personal use.  That includes making changes and additions to the open source code.

Comment: Because VS Code is Open Source and MIT Licensed, they are not limited to personal use. They could even sell it.